# VueJS 3 - Extraneous quotes in shallowReactive object of refs

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have, *for very [good reasons](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) completely irrelevant to this this question*, a shallowReactive object comprised of individual string refs.

```
const selections = shallowReactive({});
selections[i] = ref("Literally any string");
```

[I have a working example here.](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

These quotes are not in the template or the string itself, I have to have stumbled onto some weird behavior with shallowReactive and/or ref. I understand this is not a typical Vue pattern. I'm hoping someone understands why this is happening and can share their knowledge.

Comment: Set `selections[i] = ref("New string").value`, this won't add any quotes.

Comment: @Bubai But then loses the ref...

Comment: If you use `{{ sel.value }} ` in your template the quotes go away